# Найти пользователей в БД  оценок студентов, у которых только одна тройка!

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть база данных, где вся таблица - это строки с оценками, каждая строка - это оценка по предмету, таким образом, строк столько, сколько оценок. Поля: `id_stud, gruppa, god, oz_q(оценка), fio(фамилия), sem(семестр)` и т. д. Нужно найти студентов, у которых только 1 тройка, причем могут быть 5 и 4 и прочие... Мне непонятно, как запрос написать нужно.
Есть набросок, ну тут выбираются строки где только тройки одни, а как узнать, что именно только одна тройка, а оценки 4 и 5 могут быть какие угодно другие и в любых количествах?
спасибо!

```
select * from(
select distinct id_stud,fio
from posl_oz
where id_fak=128
group by id_stud,fio
having min(oz_q)=3 and max(oz_q)=3
 )

having count(oz_q)=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select id_stud,fio,count(*) from posl_oz where id_fak=128 and oz_q=3 group by id_stud,fio having count(*)=1`

Comment: count(*) можно и не выбирать - он же всегда будет равен 1, а в остальном верно.

Comment: спасибо, я только одного не пойму, почему когда в select count(*) убираешь выдает больше строк, в том числе те пользователи где троек больше чем одна?

Comment: потому что стоит `having`...